# g++ builds in wrong directory: ${workspaceFolder}\file.exe instead of ${fileDirname}\file.exe

Tags: visual-studio-code, g++, mingw-w64, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

Summary:

While in tasks.json the destination argument for g++ is clearly `"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"`, it decides to build in `"${workplaceFolder}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"` ...

Example case:

folder structure:

- cpp

  - .vscode

    - tasks.json
  - folder1

    - folder2

      - example.cpp

in tasks.json:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
      "command": "C:\\dev\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],
      "options": { "cwd": "C:\\dev\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin"  },
      "problemMatcher": [ "$gcc" ],
      "group": { "kind": "build",  "isDefault": true   },
      "detail": "compiler: C:\\dev\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
    }
  ]
}
```

in example.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Why do i not get compiled in "cpp/folder1/folder2"?";
  return 0;
}
```

In vscode with cpp folder opened as workplace:
Pressing Ctrl+Shift+B to build now causes g++ to build the example.exe at cpp/example.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue and one that got fixed yesterday. Have to wait for the next C/c++ vscode extension update:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6501

Answer (score 0):

Please provide in some way a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It helps people to understand your problem so we can give you an answer more easily.

From what I could understand from your question maybe you just compiled the `.exe` file in another directory? (again, since you didn't provide any [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I couldn't exactly understand your error)

Maybe try putting something like this in `args`:

```
"-g",
"${file}",
"-o",
"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
```

Comment: What you have suggested is already written in tasks.json.